# Netbeans deletes initial whitespace in C++ comments; make it stop

Tags: c++, netbeans, code-formatting, editing

NetBeans 8.0 and versions before. In C++, both source and headers: If I start adding a line to a comment by starting with spaces or a tab, upon hitting the first following space, the editor deletes the initial whitespace:

Intended:

> ```
> /*
>     Old comment
>     You *want to add more here*
> */
> ```

Actual:

> ```
> /*
>     Old comment
>  You *get 'helpfully' corrected as soon as you hit the first space*
>  */
> ```

How do I turn this off?

EDIT: It's actually more complex than I noticed--it's deleting all initial whitespace, then quietly adding a one-space-wide column, including the final */.  Since the text lined up with the ending */, and I'd typed *that* in the 0th column, I was assuming all the text was in the 0th column instead of the 1st column.  I want the initial spaces/tabs I type to remain.

Also note that if you go back in and add the spaces at the beginning by hand, after there's at least one word on the line and it's trimmed, it doesn't trim it a second time, but leaves it.  The current workaround is to type a line, it gets trimmed, go back to the beginning, add more spaces, continue.

Comment: Does it still happen if you do
`/*
Something like
this?
*/`
Ugh dumb mini-Markdown won't do newlines.  What I mean is if you unindent the first line, (to put the text even with the comment markers) does it still unindent the line after even further?

Comment: The first line of comment on the same line as the initial /* appears immune to the initial space deletion.  Subsequent lines still get trimmed.  It does not matter whether a previous line is indented or unindented after that--initial spaces still get trimmed.

Comment: ping--still outstanding, needed, unanswered, 0 for 0.